# JAXB marshalling, ignore nillable

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a class with variables with annotation nillable=true and I don't want them to show up in the xml. The class is generated from an xsd which can't be altered.

Example:
A class looking somththing like this:

```
public class Hi {
    ...
    @XmlElement(name = "hello", nillable = true)
    protected Long hello;
    ...
}
```

The object gets marshalled with JAXBContext created marshaller. The generated xml turns into:

```
...
<hello xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
...
```

The class Hi is generated from an xsd that can't be altered. My question is, is there a way to make the marshaller ignore the nillable argument and not output anything to the xml if "hello" is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nicolas Filotto I managed to get it to work according to my needs, here's the final code for the xmlstreamwriter (DelegateXMLStreamWriter just passes the calls to the input delegate) :

Note: This will still print nillable elements that are'nt null but does not write ANY attributes or namespace to these elements. I haven't tested if it works if a parent is nillable but a child is set.

```
public class XMLExportStreamWriter extends DelegateXMLStreamWriter {

private Set<String> nillableElements;
private final Stack<String> path = new Stack<>();

private boolean nillable;
private boolean notNull;

private String localName;
private String namespaceURI;
private String prefix;

public XMLExportStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter delegate) throws XMLStreamException {
    super.setDelegate(delegate);
}

public void setNillableElements(Set<String> nillableElements) {
    this.nillableElements = nillableElements;
}

@Override
public void writeStartElement(String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!isNillable(localName)) {
        super.writeStartElement(localName);
    } else {
        setElementArgs(null, localName, null);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeStartElement(String namespaceURI, String localName) throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!isNillable(localName)) {
        super.writeStartElement(namespaceURI, localName);
    } else {
        setElementArgs(null, localName, namespaceURI);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI)
    throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!isNillable(localName)) {
        super.writeStartElement(prefix, localName, namespaceURI);
    } else {
        setElementArgs(prefix, localName, namespaceURI);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeEndElement() throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!this.nillable || this.notNull) {
        super.writeEndElement();
    }
    this.path.pop();
    if (this.nillable) {
        this.nillable = this.nillableElements.contains(toPath());
    }
}

@Override
public void writeCharacters(String text) throws XMLStreamException {
    if (this.nillable) {
        if (text != null) {
            this.notNull = true;
            forceStartElement();
            super.writeCharacters(text);
        }
    } else {
        super.writeCharacters(text);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeCharacters(char[] text, int start, int len) throws XMLStreamException {
    if (this.nillable) {
        if (text != null) {
            this.notNull = true;
            forceStartElement();
            super.writeCharacters(text, start, len);
        }
    } else {
        super.writeCharacters(text, start, len);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeAttribute(String localName, String value) throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!this.nillable) {
        super.writeAttribute(localName, value);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeAttribute(String namespaceURI, String localName, String value)
    throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!this.nillable) {
        super.writeAttribute(namespaceURI, localName, value);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeAttribute(String prefix, String namespaceURI, String localName, String value)
    throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!this.nillable) {
        super.writeAttribute(prefix, namespaceURI, localName, value);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeNamespace(String prefix, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
    if (!this.nillable) {
        super.writeNamespace(prefix, namespaceURI);
    }
}

private void forceStartElement() throws XMLStreamException {
    if (this.prefix != null) {
        super.writeStartElement(this.prefix, this.localName, this.namespaceURI);
    } else if (this.namespaceURI != null) {
        super.writeStartElement(this.namespaceURI, this.localName);
    } else {
        super.writeStartElement(this.localName);
    }
}

private boolean isNillable(String localName) {
    this.notNull = false;
    this.path.push(localName);
    this.nillable = this.nillableElements.contains(toPath());
    return this.nillable;
}

private void setElementArgs(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.localName = localName;
    this.namespaceURI = namespaceURI;
}

private String toPath() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String element : this.path) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            sb.append('/');
        }
        sb.append(element);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

I also modified the paths to skip methods to take collections into account:

```
private static Set<String> pathsToSkip(Class<?> clazz) {
    // Make sure that the class is annotated with XmlRootElement
    XmlRootElement rootElement = clazz.getAnnotation(XmlRootElement.class);
    if (rootElement == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("XmlRootElement is missing");
    }
    // Create the root name from the annotation or from the class name
    String rootName = ("##default".equals(rootElement.name()) ?
    clazz.getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + clazz.getSimpleName().substring(1) :
    rootElement.name());
    // Set that will contain all the paths
    Set<String> pathsToSkip = new HashSet<>();        
    addPathsToSkip(rootName, clazz, pathsToSkip);
    return pathsToSkip;
}

private static void addPathsToSkip(String parentPath, Class<?> clazz, 
                               Set<String> pathsToSkip) {
    // Iterate over all the fields
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        XmlElement xmlElement = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
        if (xmlElement != null) {
            // Create the name of the element from the annotation or the field name
            String elementName = ("##default".equals(xmlElement.name()) ?
            field.getName() :
            xmlElement.name());
            String path = parentPath + "/" + elementName;
            if (xmlElement.nillable()) {
                // It is nillable so we add it to the paths to skip
                pathsToSkip.add(path);
            } else {
                // It is not nillable so we check the fields corresponding 
                // to the field type

                // If it's a collection we need to get the generic type
                if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                    ParameterizedType fieldGenericType = (ParameterizedType) field
                        .getGenericType();
                    Class<?> fieldGenericTypeClass = (Class<?>) fieldGenericType
                        .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                    addPathsToSkip(path, fieldGenericTypeClass, pathsToSkip);
                } else {
                    addPathsToSkip(path, field.getType(), pathsToSkip);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's called by something like:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));
XMLExportStreamWriter exportStreamWriter = new XMLExportStreamWriter(XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(
                bufferedWriter);
exportStreamWriter.setNillableElements(getNillablePaths(MyClass.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to implement a [decorator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm) of type `XMLStreamWriter` and implement your filter in it.

Here is a very basic and naive one (that doesn't cover many things like namespace and many other things), that could work in your case, but it is not meant to be perfect, it is just meant to show the idea:

```
public class FilteredXMLStreamWriter implements XMLStreamWriter {
    private final XMLStreamWriter writer;
    private final Set<String> pathsToSkip;
    private final Stack<String> path = new Stack<>();
    private boolean ignore;

    public FilteredXMLStreamWriter(XMLStreamWriter writer, Set<String> pathsToSkip) {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.pathsToSkip = pathsToSkip;
    }

    /**
     * Build the current path from the Stack
     */
    private String toPath() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (String element : path) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                sb.append('/');
            }
            sb.append(element);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) 
        throws XMLStreamException {
        // Add the current
        path.push(localName);
        if (!ignore) {
            this.ignore = pathsToSkip.contains(toPath());
            if (!ignore) {
                this.writer.writeStartElement(prefix, localName, namespaceURI);
            }
        }
    }
    ...

    public void writeEndElement() throws XMLStreamException {
        if (ignore) {
            this.ignore = !pathsToSkip.contains(toPath());
        } else {
            this.writer.writeEndElement();
        }
        path.pop();
    }
    ...

    public void writeCharacters(String text) throws XMLStreamException {
        if (!ignore) {
            this.writer.writeCharacters(text);
        }
    }

    public void writeCharacters(char[] text, int start, int len) 
        throws XMLStreamException {
        if (!ignore) {
            this.writer.writeCharacters(text, start, len);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Here is a naive way to get the paths to skip:

```
private static Set<String> pathsToSkip(Class<?> clazz) {
    // Make sure that the class is annotated with XmlRootElement
    XmlRootElement rootElement = clazz.getAnnotation(XmlRootElement.class);
    if (rootElement == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("XmlRootElement is missing");
    }
    // Create the root name from the annotation or from the class name
    String rootName = ("##default".equals(rootElement.name()) ?
        clazz.getSimpleName().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + clazz.getSimpleName().substring(1) :
        rootElement.name());
    // Set that will contain all the paths
    Set<String> pathsToSkip = new HashSet<>();        
    addPathsToSkip(rootName, clazz, pathsToSkip);
    return pathsToSkip;
}

private static void addPathsToSkip(String parentPath, Class<?> clazz, 
                                   Set<String> pathsToSkip) {
    // Iterate over all the fields
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        XmlElement xmlElement = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
        if (xmlElement != null) {
            // Create the name of the element from the annotation or the field name
            String elementName = ("##default".equals(xmlElement.name()) ?
                field.getName() :
                xmlElement.name());
            String path = parentPath + "/" + elementName;
            if (xmlElement.nillable()) {
                // It is nillable so we add it to the paths to skip
                pathsToSkip.add(path);
            } else {
                // It is not nillable so we check the fields corresponding 
                // to the field type
                addPathsToSkip(path, field.getType(), pathsToSkip);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then here is how you will then call it:

```
marshaller.marshal(
    myObject, 
    new FilteredXMLStreamWriter(
        XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(sw),
        pathsToSkip(Hi.class)
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The problem is that the xsd file might be updated and I need a solution that specifically targets variables that are null and has nillable annotation without hardcoding the names for each variable.

Comment: Do you have sub elements ?

Comment: Here is a dynamic Way to do the trick, that needs to be improved but at least you have a good start

Comment: Yes, there are subelements.Thanks for the update, one problem with your example is that it skips elements even if they aren't null, but I think I have a workaround for that. I'll give it a shot and get back with results.

Comment: Thanks again, I got it working as intended with some modification, I posted my full answere.